# Find the area of the triangle using $\frac12\|u\| \,\|v-\operatorname{proj}_u(v)\| $

Tags: linear-algebra, triangles, area

Real stuck on this and I'm sure I went wrong somewhere. Here is the question.

> Using points $A=(1, -1)$; $B=(2,2)$; $C=(4,0)$ find the area of the triangle.

The book states that the way to find it one way is:
$$\frac12\|u\| \,\|v-\operatorname{proj}_u(v)\| $$  So I started out by finding the vectors I used u as AC and v as AB which gave me vertices as: $u=[3, -1]$; $v=[1, 3]$

I then calculated the length of u to be $\sqrt{10}$

I then proceeded to find the length of v and the projection of v onto u.

$$v=[1, 3]$$

$$proj= \left[\frac{27}{10}, \frac{-9}{10}\right]$$

I then minused the v from proj by subtraction rule of dot product so the setup (I think) was: $1-\frac{27}{10}+3-\frac{9}{10}$

Now the length I think should've been $\sqrt{\frac{2^2}{5^2}}$

I then multiplied that result by the $\frac12 \sqrt{10}$

$\frac12\sqrt{10}*\sqrt{\frac{4}{25}}$

$\frac12\sqrt{\frac{8}{5}}$

the answer is $\frac{\sqrt{45}}{2}$

where did I get so lost?

Comment: $$v=AC=(4,0)-(1,-1)=(3,1)\neq(3,-1)$$

Comment: I didn't even notice that. thank you.

Comment: We can even add that $u=(3,-1)$ and $v=(1,3)$ would lead to a scalar product that solves the problem quite quickly by the way.

Comment: Advice: draw a diagram and mark the direction of the vectors. Then it would have been obvious that $u$ was wrong.

Comment: I am still getting the wrong answer. now I'm getting: $$ \frac12*\sqrt{\frac{288}{5}}$$

Comment: I've already tried 4 times and I keep getting $\;4\;$...too late for me, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

the first mistake you made is in calculating the vectors, since:

$$
A=(1,-1)\\
B=(2,2)\\
C=(4,0)\\
$$

I choose $u=B-A=(1,3)$ ;   $v=C-A=(3,1)$

$Area=\frac{1}{2}||v|| *||u-proj_v(u)||$

so we will calculate every term:

$$
||v||  = \sqrt{3^2+1^2} = \sqrt{10}\\
proj_v(u)  = \frac{dot(u,v)}{dot(v,v)}v = \frac{3}{5}(3,1)\\
u-proj_v(u) = (1,3)-\frac{3}{5}(3,1)=\frac{4}{5}(-1,3)\\
||u-proj_v(u)||=\frac{4}{5}\sqrt{10}
$$
now let's substitute:
$$
Area=\frac{1}{2}||v|| *||u-proj_v(u)||=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{10}\frac{4}{5}\sqrt{10}=4
$$

I hope i did not make any mistake, but i believe that the correct answer to the book problem, is the one derived here...
EDIT. checked against Heron's formula, same result

Comment: Well, so I wasn't, apparently, wrong: the area is $\;4\;$ ...

Comment: the book says $\frac{\sqrt{45}}{2}$ is the answer.